# How to open and close a window with a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two functions, one that will show a window and one that will hide a window. When the window is first created it will create a tab like link at the top of the page. What I'm wanting to do is when the user clicks that tab it will hide the window and if pressed again it will show the window. How do I determine if the window is open or closed?

Basically the window will be created and added to the navbar

```
<li onclick='tabWindowOpen(window.name)'>" + name + "</li>
```

Then on click it will call the function tabWindowOpen

```
function tabWindowOpen(name) {
    if(// it hasnt been click) {
        hideWindow(name);
    } 
    else if (// it has been clicked) {
        showWindow(name);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you can all "active" to class, in the if statement, check if that li tag has class active.

Comment: its strange, post you html too... I think something about .toggle function in jquery, or .show and .hide.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery does that for you, and you should be using event handlers:

```
'<li class="my-li-class">' + name + '</li>'

$(document).on('click', '.my-li-class', function(window.name) {
    $(window.name).toggle();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/toggle